# Defining check condition on other table

Tags: sql, database-design, oracle11g

I have tables as follows:

#### tank table

```
CREATE TABLE fishtank(
tanknum number(8),
temperature number(6,2),
capacity number(10),
primary key(tanknum));

Name        Null     Type        
----------- -------- ----------- 
TANKNUM     NOT NULL NUMBER(8)   
TEMPERATURE          NUMBER(6,2) 
CAPACITY             NUMBER(10)
```

#### Fish type

```
CREATE TABLE type(
species varchar2(20),
mintemp number(6,2),
maxtemp number(6,2),
primary key(species));


Name    Null     Type         
------- -------- ------------ 
SPECIES NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20) 
MINTEMP          NUMBER(6,2)  
MAXTEMP          NUMBER(6,2)
```

#### Eats

```
CREATE TABLE eats(
species1 varchar2(20),
species2 varchar2(20),
primary key(species1, species 2),
foreign key(species1) references type,
foreign key(species2) references type);

Name     Null     Type         
-------- -------- ------------ 
SPECIES1 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20) 
SPECIES2 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
```

Now it is like this there is a fish tank with different species. I would like to insert fish into the tank. Eats specifies which two species eat each other. If we have values in eats like

```
species1='a' species2='b'
```

this means that species 'a' eats 'b' and so we cannot place both of them in the same tank. Now I'm trying to create a table called fish which should have

```
name
species
tanknum
```

and while creating the table I would like to add a condition here that the any two fish in same tank should not eat each other. I want to implement this using check constraint and I'm working on oracle SQL. Need some help.

Comment: I would not use a trigger for this -- it's application logic that ought to be implemented in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya dude just check this!!!!is any clarification let me know!!!!

```
 create or replace
TRIGGER check_fish before
INSERT ON fish_in_tank FOR EACH row DECLARE

Type rec_2 IS TABLE OF fish_in_tank%rowtype;
fish_dup rec_2;
no_insert EXCEPTION;
BEGIN

SELECT name,
SPECIES,
tanknum bulk collect
INTO fish_dup
FROM fish_in_tank
WHERE SPECIES IN
(SELECT case when species1=:new.species then species2 when species2=:new.species then species1 end FROM Eats );

dbms_output.put_line(fish_dup(1).name);
FOR i IN fish_dup.first..fish_dup.last
LOOP
IF (:new.tanknum=fish_dup(i).tanknum) THEN
raise no_insert;
END IF;
END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
WHEN no_insert THEN

raise_application_error(-20000,'Cannot insert');
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
dbms_output.put_line('Successful');
END;
```

Comment: I would like to implement this using check constraint. Is any solution possible ??

Comment: oh..nice idea dude even i tried first like this..wait let u know

Answer (score 1):

A trigger would be good solution

```
    create trigger prevent 
    on fish 
    for insert 
    as 
begin
    if ( CASE when inserted.species IN (SELECT DISTINCT (species2) FROM fish f JOIN eats e ON f.species= e.species1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

    /* Cancel the insert and print a message.*/

        rollback transaction; 
        print "No fish eating allowed!." ;

    /* Otherwise, allow it. */
    else
      print "Added!";
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: The relational way would be to use a database constraint; SQL standards would call for an assertion. But I don't think anybody's implemented either of those features yet. So, trigger.

Comment: @Wawrzyniec Sz:how can you rollback in normal triggers?